# Disable sorting on all columnn when using jQuery DataTables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

i am using datatables of jquery to sort the table fields.my question is how to disable sorting of all column? My code is,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').dataTable();
    });

    $('#myTable').DataTable({

        bFilter: false,aDataSort :false,
        paging: true,
        displayLength : 25

    });
    $('#myTable').dataTable({
        "aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        { "bSortable": false },
        null
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#myTable').dataTable( {
"bSort": false
});
```

Or this

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
    { "bSortable": false },
    { "bSortable": false },
    { "bSortable": false },
    { "bSortable": false }
    ]
});
```